# Can the sidequest for oculus quests install on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, games, virtualization, cloud

Shadow servers have support for Ubuntu 18.04, giving support for strong portable PCs. Through the side quest app, and virtual desktop, and a powerbank, you could use a raspberry pi 4 to play half life alyx, or subnautica, on the quest 2. I don't have any Linux machines to test it on currently so I wanted to ask if anyone has, or could test to see if sidequestvr would work properly on Ubuntu 18.04.